# What does "webhook" mean

Tags: api, webhooks

I'm a fairly new React and Express developer. I'm working on a project that uses a payment provider like Stripe for the payment on the website.

The dashboard of the provider allows me to regenerate/view my API keys, and input a webhook URL, which I have no idea about.

All I know so far, is that a webhook notifies me of an event. But how does it do that? If my website is called https://example.com, and I use https://example.com/payment as the webhook URL, what will it do?

I'm completely new to this term, so any help will be appreciated in helping me understand this concept.

MUCH THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their backend will POST data to your backend endpoint when the event occurs.

It's a lot like how your frontend would call an API endpoint on your backend to submit data.